# Subprocess.run is not equivalent to subprocess.getoutput if an argument has single or double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, scp

I am using scp to transfer some file from Linux to Windows in python.

The raw scp command is `sshpass -p mypassword scp StartSaving.tmp Administrator@192.168.31.57:'"F:/data_save"'`

I use `'"..."'` beacuse I want to support directory with spaces.

I defined two variables win_password and config_path in python.

- `win_password = "mypassword"`
- `config_path = "Administrator@192.168.31.57:" + "'\"" + "F:/data_save" + "\"'"`

If I use subprocess.getoutput, the following works:

```py
subprocess.getoutput("sshpass -p " + win_password + " scp StartSaving.tmp " + config_path)
```

However, when using subprocess.run, it will not.

```py
subprocess.run(["sshpass", "-p", win_password, "scp", "StartSaving.tmp", config_path])
```

It will tell me that `scp:'F:/data_save': No such file or directory`

It seems that subprocess.run escapes the `\"` in the string.

subprocess.run should be equivilent with subprocess.getoutput

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with `run` vs. `getoutput`, it's entirely a matter of string vs. list for the command (which normally corresponds to a choice between `shell=True` and `shell=False`).  If the parameters are supplied in a list, no quoting is needed, each element is a distinct parameter even if it contains spaces or other problematic characters.

Comment: Any function, like `subprocess.getoutput` whose documentation states "executing cmd in a shell." should have a bold warning that says "Do not use unless you know what you are doing." As @jasonharper points out that function has very different semantics than `subprocess.run` due to the shell that mediates the command executed by `subprocess.getoutput`. In general you should **never** use a function that runs your command via an intermediary shell.

Comment: The problem isn't with `getoutput`, but with `run`. I know this is a matter of string vs list. The problem is passing an argument with `'"F:/data_save"'` to `subprocess.run` like the config_path assignment I given above will give me the wrong output. If I use print(config_path), I can verify the string is correct. However, subprocess.run will treat '"F:/data_save"' as 'F:/data_save' for some reason.